# Excel VBA to create a visual timeline of events using an XY scatter chart

Tags: vba, excel

I have details of key decisions made by a business in a worksheet "Decision Record."

My data is laid out as follows:

[image: Range sample]

I have written some code to create a timeline of these decisions using an XY scatter chart, like this one:

[image: Timeline sample]

The code works fine, but as with most of the code I write, it doesn't look tidy to me. Perhaps it's because of the long `with` statement, which seems like it could be simplified, maybe with a separate `with` statement for the `DataLabels` method.

Is this good practice? Is there something else I should be doing to tidy this up?

```
Sub UpdateDecisionTimelineChart()

    Dim scount As Integer
    Dim labelrotation As Integer
    Dim c As Range

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("chtDecisionTimeline").Activate
    scount = 0
        For Each c In Range(Worksheets("Decision Record").Range("C7"), Worksheets("Decision Record").Range("C7").End(xlDown))
        scount = scount + 1
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(scount)
            .Name = "='Decision Record'!" & c.Offset(0, 1).Address
            .XValues = "='Decision Record'!" & c.Address
            .Values = "='Decision Record'!" & c.Offset(0, -1).Address
            .MarkerStyle = 8
            .MarkerSize = 7
            .MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(228, 10, 56)
            .MarkerForegroundColor = -2
            .Format.Line.Visible = False
            .ApplyDataLabels
            .DataLabels.ShowValue = False
            .DataLabels.ShowSeriesName = True
            .DataLabels.Position = xlLabelPositionAbove
            .DataLabels.Orientation = -45
        End With
        Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable names could use some tidying up-

Instead of `c` why not `record` as they are in the "Decision Record"

`labelrotation` should be `labelRotation` - [Standard VBA naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1s46s4ew(v=vs.140).aspx) have `camelCase` for local variables and `PascalCase` for other variables and names.

Same goes for `scount` - `sCount` or even `recordCount`

---

Integers - [integers are obsolete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long/26409520#26409520). According to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa164506(v=office.10).aspx) VBA *silently* converts all integers to `long`.

---

Be sure to avoid things like `.Activate` - it just slows the code down by needing to fiddle with the spreadsheet while doing everything else behind the scenes. There's a good question on StackOverflow addressing this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros .

```
Dim timelineChart As Chart
    Set timelineChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("chtDecisionTimeline")
    ...

        timelineChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        With timelineChart.SeriesCollection(scount)
```

Speaking of structure, your spacing is a little off - your `with` block is the same level as your `for` block. Try pushing the loop back so alignment is correct -

```
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateDecisionTimelineChart()

    Dim sCount As Long
    Dim labelrotation As Long
    Dim record As Range

    Dim timelineChart As Chart
    Set timelineChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("chtDecisionTimeline")
    sCount = 0
    For Each record In Range(Worksheets("Decision Record").Range("C7"), Worksheets("Decision Record").Range("C7").End(xlDown))
        sCount = sCount + 1
        timelineChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        With timelineChart.SeriesCollection(sCount)
            .Name = "='Decision Record'!" & record.Offset(0, 1).Address
            .XValues = "='Decision Record'!" & record.Address
            .Values = "='Decision Record'!" & record.Offset(0, -1).Address
            .MarkerStyle = 8
            .MarkerSize = 7
            .MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(228, 10, 56)
            .MarkerForegroundColor = -2
            .Format.Line.Visible = False
            .ApplyDataLabels
            .DataLabels.ShowValue = False
            .DataLabels.ShowSeriesName = True
            .DataLabels.Position = xlLabelPositionAbove
            .DataLabels.Orientation = -45
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

---

The object model for the [series object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn301021.aspx) doesn't really specify any of the attributes' defaults, so I think your `With` block is pretty clean. You might want to create some variables or something like -

```
Dim decisionRecord As String
decisionRecord = "='Decision Record'!"

        .Name = decisionRecord & record.Offset(0, 1).Address
        .XValues = decisionRecord & record.Address
        .Values = decisionRecord & record.Offset(0, -1).Address
```

---

Your `xlDown` could be fixed like this -

```
Dim decisionRecordSheet As Worksheet
Set decisionRecordSheet = Worksheets("Decision Record")
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = decisionRecordSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
Dim recordRange As Range
Set recordRange = decisionRecordSheet.Range(Cells(7, 3), Cells(lastRow, 3))
...
For Each record In recordRange
```

---

With all these variables using the sheet, why not use the `CodeName` - Worksheets have a `CodeName` property - View Properties window (F4) and the `(Name)` field can be used as the worksheet name. This way you can avoid `Sheets("mySheet")` and instead just use `mySheet`.

---

Unless you need it to be `Public` you should make it private

```
Private Sub UpdateDecisionTimelineChart()
```

Also, I don't see you ever using the `labelRotation` variable, so unless that part was removed, you don't need it.

Comment: to the editor @Jon Peltier if you come back, I rolled back because I don't see why VBE would convert *back* to integer. If you have a source for that, I would be happy to include it.

Comment: Because your variable is an Integer, and VBA tries to put the Long value back into your Integer. If the Long value is too large for an Integer, you blow up the variable. No source for that other than private conversation with forgotten individuals long ago.

Comment: @JonPeltier the type checking still occurs. As far as the VBE is concerned, it's still an 16 bit int. it's just represented as a 32 bit integer at the OS level. I'd be interested in hearing more about about what you were trying to say/have experienced with this.

Comment: Maybe it's this checking that fails, because the value is too large to fit in an Integer, not an actual conversion back to Integer. I must admit I'm not really an expert here, just telling a story that made sense to me when I heard it ages ago.